# I want to type contraction of 3*3*3 matrices (the triple dot product symbol), how to write?

Tags: matrices

please help me in writing this equation in Latex

[image: picture]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436)  Probably `\therefore` which is provided by the `amssymb` package suits your needs.

Answer (score 2):

My welcome to the TeX.SE... I have added a fast answer....with the suggestion of the very nice user @egreg.

```
 \documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
    \usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
    \usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}
    \begin{document}
    $21(\boldsymbol{\mathrm{n}}_{ab}^{(3)}\mathbin{\therefore}\boldsymbol{\Omega}_{a})(\boldsymbol{\mu}_b\cdot\boldsymbol{\mathrm{n}}_{ba})$.
    \end{document}
```

[image: Done]

Comment: Probably `\mathbin{\therefore}`, because `\therefore` is defined to be a relation symbol.

Comment: @egreg I have approved :-).

Comment: I’d recommend `\boldsymbol` (from `amsmath`/`amsbsy`) over `\bm`.  The `bm` package redefines `\boldsymbol`, so it will work correctly with or without `bm` loaded. You’ll thank yourself if you ever want to change your stylesheet.

Comment: @Davislor Done using your suggestion. :-)